# Importing CSV with empty values AsterixDB

Tags: sql, csv

Im using the following code to load a csv file into my database, However, any time there is an empty field it seems to skip the entire row. For example test,1,3 works but test1,1,  doesn't create an entry. Does anyone know why it does this or how to fix it?

```
drop dataverse csv if exists;
create dataverse csv;
use csv;

create type csv_type as {
    Cross_Street: string,
    lat: int32,
    long: int32?
};

create dataset csv_set (csv_type)
  primary key lat;


  load dataset csv_set using localfs
      (("path"="127.0.0.1:///Users/nicholassantini/Downloads/test 2.csv"),
       ("format"="delimited-text"));


 SELECT *
     FROM csv_set csv_type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting the developers email thread I was able to find the source of this issue. It turns out that the problem was twofold. The first part of the solution was that I needed to specify that null could be an acceptable option for the fields. This is done by adding the tag ("null": "") to the field

The second problem was that I accidentally had two duplicate primary keys in my CSV file. To solve this it is best to use an autogenerated key. It is also worth noting that you cannot leave the primary key field blank. I think I did this a few times as well.

After adding those two fixes the data now imports correctly